# Call MediaCapture.InitializeAsync from UWP BackgroundTask

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal, background-task

I am trying to take a photo during a BackgroundTask at an UWP application.
I read at [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.initializeasync.aspx) that InitializeAsync should be on the STA thread but is there some approach to achieve that from a MTA? I don't known, something like Dispatchers or others workarounds.

In my actual scenario, when I call CapturePhotoToStreamAsync just after the InitializeAsync, the following exception occurs:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC00D3E82): A media
>   source cannot go from the stopped state to the paused state.

The funny thing is that it works if my app is not suspended.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you will get it to work in *BackgroundTask* - [as MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/br241124):

> InitializeAsync should be called from the main UI thread of your app. For more information, see Guidelines for enabling sensitive devices.