# Media Capture background task UWP Windows 10

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, universal

I am working on a voice recorder universal app.As part of it i have declared a background task and registered it.In the run method of the background task,i am defining a media capture object and using the below command to initialize it

```
await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(captureInitSettings);
```

I read in the msdn documentation that this call should only happen in STA thread.So my background task is not working.

Any ideas on how i can record audio even when the user minimizes the app.

Error Message :

> Inside StartRecording . initializing mediacapture opbject initialize
>   async
>   **Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll**

Comment: As far as I know there is not possible to record audio from background in UWP.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have seen few apps in the store do that.I am not sure if they are using mediacpature or another way.

also my code works in windows 10 PC but not in Windows 10 Mobile

Comment: I don't think an UWP app can record audio from background either. But if there are some apps have this ability in the store, could you please provide us some links, so can we do some investigations?

Comment: It is not a uwp app .However it is a Windows Phone 8.1 app i guess.
Voice Recorder Free +.
I will keep looking if there are any other apps of this kind.
Thanks for your response

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119740/call-mediacapture-initializeasync-from-uwp-backgroundtask

Comment: Did you find the answer?